# autowired entries are null when using @Scheduled annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-4

Spring version 4.2.0.RELEASE

Given following class, config member becomes null when cleanDocumentMirror method is executed by spring. My code is essentially similar to [spring example](http://spring.io/blog/2010/01/05/task-scheduling-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/). Its not just this field, but all other autowired fields are null.

I have afterPropertiesSet method, and that method is referring to config member and it does not fail or in otherwords members are auto wired correctly. Application does start correctly and does work correctly as all dependencies are injected correctly. Only when this method is called, I see all autowired entries as null.

The class has some methods with @JmsListener annotation and when spring invokes those methods, members look correct. Only when scheduled method is called, I face the problem. So likely I need to enable some settings.

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
@Transactional(value = "somevalue")
@EnableTransactionManagement()
public class DownloadResponseListener implements InitializingBean {
     @Autowired
     AggregatorConfig config;

  @JmsListener(destination = "response_queue", containerFactory = "mqConnectionContainerFactory") 
public void process(final ObjectMessage message) {
    config.getConfigrationValue(); // works correctly here.
    }

  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5 * 1000)
  void cleanDocumentMirror() {
       config.getConfigrationValue(); // causes NPE here as config is null
  }
}
```

Comment: How is your scheduler configured?

Comment: @dunni, what do you mean? I have just declared the annotation, we don't have any xml files, everything is configuration based. The method does get called at desired frequency.

Comment: You can retrieving it through ApplicationContext getBean method.

Comment: So you are using Spring Boot? Or do you deploy your application in an application server?

Comment: Its application server, a web application to be precise. This class is one of the most important class in the application as it communicates with backend. Generally it behaves ok - does get JMS messages etc. However this is the only case where I am seeing it failing.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. I found that after adding the `@Scheduled` annotation, Spring actually created the bean twice -- once correctly, and once without any of the dependencies, which was being executed by the task scheduler.

In my case, it was because the method annotated with `@Scheduled` was final and I guess this was causing issues with Spring's automagic proxying mechanism.

In Kotlin, all classes are final by default, therefore this is a common problem. When using Spring with Kotlin, consider use of the [kotlin-spring plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html#spring-support) to automatically compile Spring-annotated classes and methods as `open`.

Try and find similar reasons in your code that Spring may not be able to proxy the object properly (it would be nice if it raised an error or even a warning in this situation!).

Comment: Easy to miss that one if you use Kotlin. This should be the marked answer, to have both class and method non final.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the method was package-private. I had to make it public and Spring was then able to inject the dependencies correctly.